# How many solutions has the following equation?

Tags: functions, polynomials

Determine how many real solutions has the following equation:
$\sqrt[5]{2x+1+2\sqrt{{x^2+1}}}+\sqrt[5]{2x+1-2\sqrt{{x^2+1}}} = 2$

My first idea was to use the graph for the square root function: f:C->D, f(x)= $\sqrt[a]{b}$, if a is odd then f(x) is increasing on R so it should have only one solution but it doesn't 'feel' right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2x%2B1%2Bsqrt(x%5E2%2B1))%5E(1%2F5)%2B(2x%2B1-sqrt(x%5E2%2B1))%5E(1%2F5)%3D2&assumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22) and click on using the real valued root finds the root is about $0.18304$

Comment: Shouldn't it be around $0.855$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined by the expression.

Notice that the second term has a value of $0$ when $x=\frac{3}{4}$ and the first term has a value of $\sqrt[5]{5}$ which is less than $2$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is

$$ \frac{1}{5}(2x+1+2\sqrt{x^2+1})^{-4/5}\left(2+\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)+ \frac{1}{5}(2x+1-2\sqrt{x^2+1})^{-4/5}\left(2-\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$

This $f^\prime(x)$ is positive for all $x>\frac{3}{4}$ so the function is increasing on the interval $\left(\frac{3}{4},\infty\right)$ and has a value smaller than $2$ at $x=\frac{3}{4}$.

Notice that $f(n^5)>n$, so the expression has no upper bound.

Thus, since the function is continuous and is increasing for $x>\frac{3}{4}$ and has a value less than $2$ at $x=\frac{3}{4}$, and has no upper bound, there is only one solution to the equation.